# Php Function that calculates the square for a series of numbers (45, 12, 1, 100, 6) the roots of each number, put them in a new array

Tags: php, arrays, function, sqrt

I need help for PHP function that calculates the square for a series of numbers (45, 12, 1, 100, 6) the roots of each number, put them in a new array, and prints on the screen. I know that the function is sqrt, but it receives only one parameter and here is a array of numbers. Also, Expand the previous example so that only whole values are stored in the new array
numbers, and this is rounded up to the upper value.

Thank you.

Comment: `array_map('sqrt', $array)` ? That's like PHP fundamentals.

Comment: Also this is not really relevant to the square API

Comment: @apokryfos if you can write me it with array_map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this like blow

```
function ceilNumbers($array) {
    $output = array();

    foreach($array as $n) {
        array_push($output, ceil(sqrt( $n )));
    }

    return $output;
}

$arrayOfNumbers = array(69, 2, 15, 10, 85);
print_r( ceilNumbers($arrayOfNumbers) );
```

Comment: Perfect man. Thank you so.

Comment: your sincerely. @AleksandarMihailovic

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple loop and use `ceil` to round the number up perhaps

```
$arr=array(45, 12, 1, 100, 6);
$out=array();

foreach( $arr as $num )$out[]=ceil( sqrt( $num ) );
print_r( $out );
```

Comment: Can you write me as function($array) {
# code....